# Generic pattern-matching for tagged unions

Tags: typescript, pattern-matching

I'm writing a generic pattern-matching function `match` to be used for tagged unions, passing an object as a matcher (to be used instead of the typical `switch (obj.kind) { ... }`). That's what I have:

```
type UnionNamespace<Obj extends { kind: string }> = {
    [K in Obj["kind"]]: Obj extends { kind: K } ? Obj : never;
};

type Matcher<Obj extends { kind: Kind }, Result, Kind extends string> = {
    [K in Kind]: (obj: UnionNamespace<Obj>[K]) => Result;
};

function match<Obj extends { kind: Kind }, Result, Kind extends string>(
    obj: Obj,
    matcher: Matcher<Obj, Result, Kind>
): Result {
    const fn = matcher[obj.kind];
    return fn(obj as Parameters<typeof fn>[0]);
}

/* Example */

type Square = { kind: "square"; side: number };
type Circle = { kind: "circle"; radius: number };
type Shape = Square | Circle;

const square = { kind: "square", side: 2 } as Shape;
const surface = match(square, {
    square: square => square.side ** 2,
    circle: circle => Math.PI * circle.radius ** 2
});

console.log(surface.toFixed()); // Op that does not type-check if surface is not a number
```

I am not completely satisfied with the code. For example, 1) I'd like to do without the hint `Kind extends string`, but then I get `Result=unknown`. Also, 2) this `Parameters<typeof fn>[0]` looks kind of clunky, but that's the only way I found to type-check the call.

Any ideas/proposals? Do you know of any existing code that does something like this?

[EDIT] Final version, with the discriminated field selectable:

https://gist.github.com/tokland/c0db1473cc9bfa924470e52bdac8450c

Answer (score 2):

I don't see anything wrong with your code; even the part where you have an "unnecessary" generic type parameter, since it helps the compiler infer what you want.

A possible modification to your approach, which you could take or leave, would be this:

```
type Matcher<Obj extends { kind: string }> = {
    [K in Obj["kind"]]: (obj: Extract<Obj, { kind: K }>) => any;
};

function match<T extends { kind: string }, M extends Matcher<T>>(
    obj: T,
    matcher: M
): ReturnType<M[T["kind"]]> {
    const fn = matcher[obj.kind as T["kind"]];
    return fn(obj as Parameters<typeof fn>[0]);
}
```

The idea here is that the compiler is much better at inferring a type parameter `X` from a value of type `X` than it is at inferring a type parameter `X` from a value of type `SomeTypeFunction<X>`.  So, I make two type parameters: `T` corresponding to `obj`, and `M` corresponding to `matcher`.  And then use type functions to compute the return type of `match(obj, matcher)` as a function of `T` and `M`... in this case, `ReturnType<M[T["kind"]]>`.

Inside the implementation of `match()`, the compiler can't seem to understand that `obj.kind` is of type `T["kind"]` without being reminded of it, but otherwise it's the same.  And it behaves similarly to yours on the example code:

```
type Square = { kind: "square"; side: number };
type Circle = { kind: "circle"; radius: number };
type Shape = Square | Circle;

const square = { kind: "square", side: 2 } as Shape;
const surface = match(square, {
    square: square => square.side ** 2,
    circle: circle => Math.PI * circle.radius ** 2
});

console.log(surface.toFixed()); // toFixed() doesn't work if not a number
```

Looks good. Of course the world is full of edge cases, so there are undoubtedly differences between the two approaches that may make one more suitable to your use cases than the other.  Anyway, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#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-X3goxggVDIAHJgFAAO7GNAMZTgsjGa9wKC8-noIA)

Comment: Thanks, @jcalz; as always, a lot of knowledge in your answers. I will explore it and see the pro/cons of each approach.